# AWS CLI(aws rds) Unknown Option : --cloudwatch-logs-export-configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface

I am trying to run aws cli to enable Postgres RDS log files export to cloudwatch(for longer retention and dashboards)
The command I ran :
aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier  --cloudwatch-logs-export-configuration '{"EnableLogTypes":["postgres", "upgrade"]}'

I get error : 
Unknown options: --cloudwatch-logs-export-configuration

In AWS documentation this is a suggested command, but in 'aws help' this option is not documented.

Comment: Have you tried updating your CLI version?

Comment: Update the cli helped

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the CLI version

1.11.139 is the latest version of awscli

if you are using pip, proceed with pip (or) pip3 install awscli --upgrade